# Using setters/getters on a text file

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am trying to make a list of coordinates from a text file and I want to be efficient with it, so I created a class that has a `latitude` and `longitude` double variables, along with their getter and setter methods.

So in the other class I make an object of the previous class to use the setter methods.

```
CoordinatesParams params = new CoordinatesParams();
```

How can I read the list of coordinates from the text file and set them to the `latitude`and `longitude`variables?

Sorry if this question is very basic to some

```
File Bus_Routes = new File("C:/Users/Daniel Dold/Desktop/Routes/Bus_Routes.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Bus_Routes);

String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] parsed = line.split("\\s");
String routeText = parsed[0];

String dir = "C:/Users/Daniel Dold/Desktop/Routes/";
File routeFile = new File(dir, routeText);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(routeFile);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
    String line2 = sc.nextLine();
    String[] s = line2.split("\t");
}
```

This is what I have so far to print the results on the file.

```
51.50177649 -0.05012445
51.50210374 -0.05050666
51.50253617 -0.0509908
51.50265346 -0.05072191
51.50274404 -0.05055025
51.50301702 -0.05011841
```

The coordinates file are just 2 columns the first being latitude and the second longitude

Comment: this depends on how are your coordinates written in the file. Also you couldn't do a google search on how to read a file?

Comment: I have just added the what I have done so far to read the file

Comment: pls show a little part of the file to know how the coordinates are stored in it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how the File looks inside, but you should creat a list for your `CoordinatesParamas` and then iterate over the data you read from the file to fill the list with `CoordinatesParamas` objects and set the latitude and longitude in this objects via setters.

```
List<CoordinatesParamas> lCoordinates = new ArrayList<CoordinatesParamas>();

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
     CoordinatesParamas temp = new CoordinatesParamas();
     String pair = sc.nextLine();
     String[] s = pair.split(" ");
     temp.setLatitude(s[0])
     temp.setLongitude(s[1])
     lCoordinates.add(temp ); 
}
```

I changed `string.split("\t")` with `split(" ")` because it looks like there is not a tab between the coordinates, only a whitespace.